# How to change table name using IEEEconf?

Tags: babel, ieeeconf

I'm trying to change the table name from "TABLE" to "Tabla" so I wrote:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt, conference]{ieeeconf}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{labelfont={sf,bf},textfont=sl,labelsep=quad}
%.....

\begin{table}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
...
\end{tabular}
\caption{Se representa el voltaje y el inverso de su raíz para distintas distancias a la boca del cornete $r$.}
\label{tabla:tabla 1}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

But the table still shows *"TABLE"*. Any possible solutions? Thanks

Comment: I don't have `ieeeconf` available at the moment, where can i get it? Completing the code to compile with standard `article` i see tabla (not table).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I get TABLA: [picture](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8fzEB.png) Note that the class should be `IEEEconf` (some systems don't distinguish case in file names, others do).

Comment: I have ieeeconf as a predefined archive in a template from Overleaf; i was unable to find anything concerning the caption enviroment on it.

Comment: Finnaly I have fix it; changing some options on ieeeconf.cls I have changed the table name.

Answer (score 2):

If I write the document properly, the caption has “Tabla”.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{IEEEconf}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
x & y & z
\end{tabular}
\caption{Se representa el voltaje y el inverso de su raíz para
  distintas distancias a la boca del cornete $r$.}
\label{tabla:tabla 1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Notes.

1. The class name is `IEEEconf.cls`; some systems don't distinguish case in file name, others do.
2. There is no `conference` option.
3. For Spanish, loading `fontenc` with the `T1` option is recommended.
4. The `caption` package is not compatible with `IEEEconf`.

If you need to use this class for a submission, *don't* change the its setup: you'll only annoy the copy editors. If you aren't making a submission to an IEEE conference, don't use the class.

[image]

Comment: The OP just made me aware of https://www.overleaf.com/4847666vvyzgz#/14871469/. It really is `ieeeconf`.

Answer (score 1):

Finnaly I have fix it; changing some options on ieeeconf.cls I have changed the table name.

```
\newcounter{table}
\def\thetable{\@Roman\c@table}
\def\fps@table{tbp}
\def\ftype@table{2}
\def\ext@table{lot}
\def\fnum@table{Tab.~\thetable}
```

Where Tab. is written TABLE was written before, just changed that.

Comment: Please note that you are not allowed to *just* change the class file. The class is iicensed under the LPPL, please read about it. As egreg hinted, your changes will be reverted when submitting to the journal.

Comment: But, it says that it uses the Perl Artistic License and may be freely used, distributed and modified.

Comment: Egreg and I are talking about IEEEconf, the current class for submissions to IEEE journals. You have some template unknown to us which indeed has `ieeeconf.cls` under that license which is a spin-off of `IEEEtrans` which has version .8b from Aug 2015 in the official repos. I am not even sure the template you are using is suited for submission.

Comment: I'm just doing an university homework so it is not for submission; sorry, I had to say it before.